# mergExt - mergAV, trying to know if the video can be saved to camera roll

Tags: video-recording, livecode

I'm trying to know if the video can be saved to camera roll of the Device.

I use Device -> Settings -> Privacy -> Photos to negate or give permission to save on Camera Roll.

1. First I tried by check before to use the command mergAVSaveVideo:

> ```
> on mergAVCamRecordingFinished pFile
>    if mergAVCanSaveVideo(pFile) then
>       answer "OK"
>    else
>       answer "NO"
>    end if 
>
>    mergAVSaveVideo pFile
> end mergAVCamRecordingFinished
> ```

It answer me "OK" also if the video is not saved.

1. Then I tryed to use the results:

> ```
> on mergAVCamRecordingFinished pFile
>    mergAVSaveVideo pFile
>    answer result
> end mergAVCamRecordingFinished
> ```

Here the answer dialog don't appears.

1. Then I tried to catch the error

> ```
>    try
>       mergAVSaveVideo pFile
>    catch e
>       answer e
>    end try
> ```

Here the error is always the same, whether it can save whether it can't save:

634,0,0 string conversion failed 573,13,1,mergAVSaveVideo.

Any advice?

Comment: Hmm... i think the string conversion failed error must be coming from the externals sdk... does it make any difference if you do something like: put pFile into tFile then call mergAVSaveVideo tFile?

Comment: Test done. Thanks. With permission to access camera roll: >634,0,0,string conversion failed 573,21,1,mergAVSaveVideo. Witout permission: >634,0,0,string conversion failed 573,21,1,mergAVSaveVideo.

Comment: PS if the access to the camera roll is given in the settings, the movie is saved regularly also if the error is present.

Comment: PPS I tried also passing a path of an existing video, same results: video saved and error present (the only change is the number 21 replaced with 10).

Comment: Actually the error happens after the command has done it's thing so as a temporary workaround you can just surround it in try/end try.

Comment: Thank you Monte. Yes, of course. Anyway I hope I explained myself. My problem is to know if the video is saved in the Camera Roll or not.

Even better to know if I can save it or not before to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you found a bug. Thanks! I'll release a new version of mergAV ASAP. BTW mergAVCanSaveVideo is working out if the video is compatible with the photos album UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum so I'll add another function for this... mergAVCanAccessPhotoLibrary...